# How IE and Chrome executes knockoutjs differently from Firefox?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, cross-browser

My viewmodel is

```
var emailModel = function (email, isPreferred) {
    this.Email = ko.observable(email);
    this.IsPreferred = ko.observable(isPreferred);
};

var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.emails = ko.observableArray([new emailModel('', false)]);
    self.addEmail = function () {
        self.emails.push(new emailModel('', false));
    };
    self.removeEmail = function (email) {
        self.emails.remove(email);
    };
    self.setPreferred = function (email) {
        if (email.IsPreferred()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.emails().length; i++) {
                if (self.emails()[i] != email)
                    self.emails()[i].IsPreferred(false);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

setPreferred works as expected in Firefox, but not in IE nor Chrome. Could anyone shed some light?

fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/xpluni/3t5HH/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Pointy the setPreferred doesn't work like radio buttons.

Comment: @Jamiec I cannot convince my client with that...

Comment: @xpluni what exactly do you mean? When I click a checkbox, any other already-checked checkbox unchecks.

Comment: @Pointy doesn't work for me under chrome. Browser issue?

Comment: If I untick any tick box they all become unticked, but I can tick multiple tickboxes.

Comment: @Pointy hmm.. what browser are you using? Neither Chrome nor IE10 works for me.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 26.0

Comment: @Pointy Firefox does work! But again I cannot convince my client to just use Firefox... Wonder why other browsers fail.

Comment: @xpluni well you'll have to do some debugging in that "setPreferred" function.

Comment: So the title of this question is now wrong. You have successfully made it do what you want, but there is some quirk of some browsers which causes it to behave unexpectedly. (FYI, works for me in FF, not in IE).

Comment: @Jamiec Got it! actually it's an issue I've known for a while. Firefox takes updated value while IE/Chrome takes old value. Solution is read updated value from element rather than knockout observable. I'll add my answer later as I'm still a new user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers and comments, I figured this out.

In setPreferred

```
self.setPreferred = function (email) {
    if (email.IsPreferred()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.emails().length; i++) {
            if (self.emails()[i] != email)
                self.emails()[i].IsPreferred(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Basically Firefox takes updated value of `email.IsPreferred` while IE/Chrome takes old value.

Solution is reading updated value from element rather than knockout observable.

```
self.setPreferred = function (email, target) {
    if (target.target.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.emails().length; i++) {
            if (self.emails()[i] != email)
                self.emails()[i].IsPreferred(false);
        }
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpluni/3t5HH/1/

Answer (score 1):

The difference here between browsers is the order by which the bindings are updated. The simple addition of 1 debugging line will show this up:

```
self.setPreferred = function (email) {
    console.log(email.IsPreferred())  <-- here
    if(email.IsPreferred()){
       ....
```

This will log to console `true` in firefox when checking a checkbox. However in IE it logs `false` as (I suspect) that binding has not yet been updated.

So in summary,

- Firefox - binds the `checked` binding then executes the `click`
- IE - executes the `click`, and then binds the `checked` property

Updated fiddle to give it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/3t5HH/2/

Comment: Shouldn't this be considered a Knockout bug?

Comment: @Pointy - Probably. Its certainly inconsistent.